# Git Error: The requested URL returned error: 504 Gateway Timeout while accessing http://

Tags: git, http-status-code-504

I am using a VM provisioned by my company's internal cloud (KVM) - RHEL 6.4.

I am able to clone external repositories from the internet. Yet, I cannot figure out how to clone internal repositories on my company's intranet.

At first I didn't set the `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` and received this error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Authorization Required while accessing http://....
```

After setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`, I now receive this error after waiting about 60 seconds:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 504 Gateway Timeout while accessing http://...
```

**I can clone this repo find from my laptop, just not the VM**

Any ideas on where I should look?

Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. @Matthew where you able to resolve it?

Comment: @TsetNoitamotua It has been a while, but I'm pretty sure what I ended up doing was switching to SSH fro HTTPS and everything started working fine. Unfortunately I cannot recall the root cause of the issue. Can you try SSH out and tell me if it works for you?

Comment: I didn't try SSH yet but I got HTTPS working by adding local adresses to a proxy exception list as described here: http://ask.xmodulo.com/add-proxy-exceptions-ubuntu-desktop.html

TL;DR - gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '*.mycompany.com', '::1']"

Comment: What also works is: export no_proxy=.yourcompany.com

Answer (score 30):

use this in .gitconfig file then this problem will resolved.

```
- [http]
     proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8087
     sslVerify = false
```

OR 
 `git config --global http.proxy ''`

Comment: it worked for me: OR  git config --global http.proxy ''

Thanks

Comment: "git config --global --unset http.proxy" command worked for me.

Comment: "git config --global --unset http.proxy" command worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The 504 status is most likely because you're trying to access an internal server through the proxy so I don't think you should set the proxy but instead focus on the 401 status since that most likely comes from the server hosting the repositories.

- Do you have anonymous access to the internal repositories?
- Are you cloning them in the same way, i.e. using HTTP on both your
  laptop and on the server, or are you using SSH on the laptop and HTTP
  on the server?
- Do you have any credentials stored on your laptop?