# Git error 504 connecting to the server

Tags: git

I am trying to use Git for the first time in my company, but when I try to clone a project or push anything to the server, I get instantly the following:

> fatal: unable to access '[my_project_name]': The requested URL returned error: 504

I said instantly because 504 is a timeout error, and is not even taking 1 sec.

The point is all my colleagues are able to connect, but something seems to be wrong in my machine or user. This is what I tried:

- A colleague from the same network can clone and push the project
- A colleague connecting to my machine via Remote Desktop can also do it with his user, so it seems git installation works fine.
- I uninstalled git and the config file and installed it again, nothing.
- I tried with and without the company proxy, same thing.
- I have a VM in this machine, from there it works with my user.
- Also works from other remote machines with my user.
- It does not even ask for the user and password, is failing before, so I guess this is not the issue.
- I can clone any other github project from the internet.
- System Admins gave me full access to the git server, and in fact it works in other machines, so i guess the server is OK.
- Finally I tried with ssh, failing as well with the message

> "connection refused by the server", I suppose caused by the same unknown issue.

I someone can give any hint it will be really appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Try pinging the server where the git repository is hosted.

Comment: It may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085607/git-error-the-requested-url-returned-error-504-gateway-timeout-while-accessing

Comment: Hi Code-Apprentice, ping works fine, and accessible from BitBucket.

Comment: Hi i_th, already read this and some others, no problem with the proxy and the credentials are not anywhere. I tried but they were never asked, is failing before this point. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround cloning the project via ssh instead of http. The http call was using the username on the url:

```
http://[username]@[git server]:[port]/../[project_name].git
```

Now I tried, after creating a pair of ssh keys and adding my public key to the git server, the following command:

```
ssh://git@[git server]:[port]/../[project_name].git
```

I am still curious about what happens with the http call, but will use this workaround by now.

For more information about generating ssh keys and including them into the git server: [ssh github](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)