# fatal: unable to access 'http://repo.***.com/***/***.git/': The requested URL returned error: 504

Tags: git, git-push, http-status-code-504, remote-repository

I can access self-hosted Git repository by browser. However, `git push` on command line throws this error:

```
$ git push origin m26.12.2--insert-auto-logic
fatal: unable to access 'http://repo.***.com/***/***.git/': The requested URL returned error: 504
```

So far, tried these without any effect:

1. Tried Git Bash on Windows 10
2. Changed my DNS server to `1.1.1.1` and `8.8.8.8`
3. Use `tor` and `proxychains` on Linux
4. Use Windows 10 command prompt
5. Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38588955/3405291) and playing around with Git proxy
6. Removing Git credentials suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/3405291)
7. Trying to use SSH like [this one](https://superuser.com/a/230728/571029)

Is there anything else I can do? Maybe, how can I use [this upload approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500082/3405291) to push my commits to remote self-hosted Git? I can see the new/upload buttons when browse the remote repository on browser:

[image: New/upload buttons on browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved by using [a system-wide VPN](https://speedify.com/download/#) on Windows 10. Not sure why.